# Yii2 User model relation not working with other table

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm working on Yii2 Advance Application. I've two tables `user` (default yii2 db schema table) and `user_profile`(newly added). I've created relation between them by adding `user_profile_id` in `user` table and also made change in their respective models.

Following code added in `User` Model:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getUserProfile() {
    return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::className(), ['id' => 'user_profile_id']);
}
```

And in `UserProfile` Model

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['user_profile_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Now, when I'm trying to pull data of `UserProfile` model from `User` gridview its giving me error:

`User` Gridview:

```
<?=
    GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            'userProfile.first_name',
            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'header' => 'Action',
                'template' => ' {update} {delete}',
            ],
        ],
    ]);
    ?>
```

(see `userProfile.first_name`)

Error:

```
Unknown Class – yii\base\UnknownClassException
Unable to find 'backend\models\UserProfile' in file: D:\www\pcwf/backend/models/UserProfile.php. Namespace missing?
```

Where I'm going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a string `namespace backend\models;` at the beginning of the UserProfile.php?

Comment: Ohh.. It was not there initially. I added and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @snegostup: I added `namespace backend\models;` there but `user/create` page is not working after that

Comment: @snegostup: create page working when I add `namespace app\models;` but index page gives error and if I add `namespace backend\models` then index works but create doesn't

Comment: "not working" is cool but it says nothing about the problem. If you provided the error messages and the code I could try to help.

Comment: Unknown Class – yii\base\UnknownClassException
Unable to find 'app\models\UserProfile' in file: D:\www\pcwf\backend/models/UserProfile.php. Namespace missing?

Comment: Above is error message for `user/create` when I add `namespace backend\models` in UserProfile.php

Comment: I think there's conflict between `namespace backend\models` and `namespace app\models`.. Am I right?

Comment: If you use the advanced template there is has no `app\models` namespace. Learn about namespaces and how to use them. And read the error messages, it's all said there in plain English.

Comment: I'm using `namespace app\models` in every model class and its working fine for me.. no issue.. only issue there in `UserProfile` model

Comment: Probably you have `use backend\models\UserProfile` in User.php. To make it work change it to `use app\models\UserProfile`, and in UserProfile.php change namespace back to `app\models`. It will work but it's completely wrong. Use `backend\models`, `frontend\models` and `common\models` namespaces. Refactor now.